# swift private module map, trying to use objC code in Swift from within framework

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, module, frameworks

pulling my hair here:
- I am developing a swift framework, today I found a nice control i want to modify its code and subclass as well. The source code is ObjC.

So (a first for me), I created a modulemap: TTRangeSlider.modulemap, simple one:

```
module TTRangeSlider {
  export *
}
```

I added the file to the project and the source files, both the modulemap and the sources in a TTRangeSlider folder inside my folder file.

I then create a xconfig file:

```
 SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS = ${SRCROOT}/MYFramework/TTRangeSlider
 MODULEMAP_PRIVATE_FILE = ${SRCROOT}/MYFramework/TTRangeSlider/TTRangeSlider.modulemap
```

Configure my project so all configurations use this xconfig file

Compiles with no issue, BUT:

trying to import the module:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import TTRangeSlider <------------ NO SUCH MODULE 'TTRangeslider'

internal class TBRangeSliderImproved  {

}
```

Comment: Did you make any further progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jason

turns out i didn't need a module map, just a bridging header as described in: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

-> Importing Code from Within the Same Framework Target

-> Importing Objective-C into Swift, hope it helps, i did have to manually set the name of the bridging header for my target under Build Settings though

Comment: I thought bridging header's aren't allowed in framework targets??